# Resharper reports "Unsupported FrameworkVersion 4.6" (even if visual studio starts up without a project)

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper

When I start visual studio, the "Resharper exception browser" comes up with an error message suggesting that I have an unsupported framework version.

Questions:

- What is having that unsupported framework version? Visual studio?
- Can I get rid of that error message without disabling resharper?
- Why did this error suddenly happen?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to an older version of ReSharper that was released before .net framework 4.6. Unfortunately, the only fix is to update to a more recent version - 9.0 fixes this, although we're currently on 10.1 (aka 2016.1)

Comment: Presumably, you've installed the .net framework 4.6, perhaps by install VS2015.

Comment: No, I only have VS2013

Comment: (but I am able to pick 4.6 when changing .NET version of a project).

Comment: I'm not sure what it is that's installed 4.6 then. But it's there, and while VS can target it, unfortunately, that version of ReSharper can't.